# php-how to echo 'get" with the formatting?

Tags: php

I have code like this in php

```
echo  get($contents,'<plaintext>','</plaintext>') ;
```

it gives me the simple plain text.
Now i want to format this echo text with increase the font size
therefore i try

```
 echo "<div style ='font:30px  Arial,tahoma,sans-serif;color:#555'>get($contents,'<plaintext>','</plaintext>') </div>";
```

but it is not working how to do this??
I try this by doing more experiment but none of the things working.
plz help me on this

Comment: Maybe?
 echo "<div style ='font:30px  Arial,tahoma,sans-serif;color:#555'>" . get($contents,'<plaintext>','</plaintext>') . "</div>";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append the function in the string. Just like this:

```
echo "<div style ='font:30px  Arial,tahoma,sans-serif;color:#555'>" . get($contents,'<plaintext>','</plaintext>') . "</div>";
```